# Абсолютные адреса в style.css

Tags: php, чпу, css

Приветствую

Использую такую штучку:

```
1. В сайт подключается style.php
2. В style.php пишется echo '<style>..';//все что в втилях
```

Плюс - по скорости работы не отличимо от style.css, генерю туда динамические адреса (нужны если использую ЧПУ). Минус - многие не понимают, да и обходятся без этого.

Вопрос: Какие альтернативы? В инете пишут что надо 2 разных файла, 1 локально для редактирования сайта, другой на самом сайте.. да и если сайт переезжает - правим адреса, что не удобно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используете ЧПУ то лучше пропишите в .htaccess строчку:

```
RewriteRule ^style.css/?$ style.php [L]
```

И в самом файле прописывайте без <style>...</style>

Чтобы не править при переезде адрес сайта создайте в index.php строку:

```
define('SITE_URL','http://ваш_домен');
```

в стилях требующих указания адреса сайта прописывайте к примеру размещение фонового рисунка:

```
background:url(".SITE_URL."/images/fon.jpeg);
```

Как то так.